# angular flex-layout performance

Tags: angular, responsive-design, angular-flex-layout, flexboxgrid

I want to build a responsive application with angular 4. I am checking some responsive platforms and of course one of the main options is [angular flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout).

I made some test pages with angular flex-layout and I saw that it doesn't use css media-queries and all the listening and responsiveness are implemented via typescript.

Could this fact cause a performance problem in mobile devices/low resources devices?
There are more responsiveness frameworks such as [flexbox-grid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flexboxgrid) which are css based only. wouldn't it be better to use css-based platforms rather than angular flex-layout from performance point of view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only noticeable performance I have encountered is when displaying large list/tables

Take a look at this page: https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Performance-Considerations

Answer (score 1):

In angular flex-layout there are break points for different width devices.
You can view all available options from below link:

https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Responsive-API

Answer (score 1):

Yes, absolutely it can cause performance issues - even on desktop, and not just with tables, if displaying a large number of elements. I personally experienced severe rendering performance due to layout thrashing.

I was experiencing page load times of more than 20 seconds. In the process of debugging this, I found that switching from the (now deprecated) flex-layout library to a CSS alternative such as [css-fx-layout](https://github.com/philmtd/css-fx-layout/issues/20), I was able to get my page load time down to under 2 seconds.